# Making form groups inside a form inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I'm trying to make the divs with class="form-group" inline with their labels on top. As is, the labels are inline with the fields and they are stack on top of each other like so:

[image]

I want to make it like so:
[image]

here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
  <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-3'>
            <form class="form-inline">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="date">DATE</label>
                <div class='col-sm-8 input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="date">DATE 2</label>
                <div class='col-sm-8 input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]please  set "form-inline". that's a class by Bootstrap for inline. I believe you are using Bootstrap.

See more details on : `https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms`

Created one fiddle : `https://jsfiddle.net/552yzg22/#&togetherjs=O18LSbynLF`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

CSS

```
.form-group{display: inline-block; }
```

This basically means that each div with the class `form-group` will display in a fashion where they stack from left to right. You could also try `float: left;`.

Answer (score -1):

You are doing it the wrong way, here's the correct way of doing it

```
https://codepen.io/the_leg3nd/pen/rGQKvB?editors=1000
```

You can add multiple rows inside the form group itself, you need not have to give any `.col-*` classes inside the `form-group` or `input-group` in this case.

Comment: I think this is not needed to use 2 columns. Bootstrap itself have a method for inline Forms. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms.

Comment: Oh shit, yes. My mistake, I thought he wanted the label to be on top of the forms. My bad :(